# Data Round off with 3 decimal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to round of the data with the below . However it throws me an error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method

df['Actual Data Reqd'] = df['Data'].round(decimals=3)
```

[image]

Comment: since all these values are greater than 99.999, rounding the data to 3 decimal places will give you 100.00. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round the data in a few ways. Note that you are trying to round the data to 3 decimal places. All values greater than `99.999` will round itself to `100.0`.

The best option is to use what you did. Not sure why you are unable to round them.

**Option 1:**

```
df['Rounded2'] = df.Data.round(3)
```

**Option 2:**

```
df['Rounded1'] = df.round({'Data':3})
```

Here's the full code and the output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[99.999824,99.999839,99.999982,
                           99.999996,99.999997,99.999971,99.999942]})
print (df)
df['Rounded1'] = df.round({'Data':3})
df['Rounded2'] = df.Data.round(3)


print (df)
```

Output of the above code:

```
        Data  Rounded1  Rounded2
0  99.999824     100.0     100.0
1  99.999839     100.0     100.0
2  99.999982     100.0     100.0
3  99.999996     100.0     100.0
4  99.999997     100.0     100.0
5  99.999971     100.0     100.0
6  99.999942     100.0     100.0
```

If you want the data to be printed in 3 decimal places, then add this line.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.3f}".format
```

Note that it will convert all the data into 3 decimal places and print. That would make your `Data` field also get printed in 3 decimal places.

```
     Data  Rounded1  Rounded2
0 100.000   100.000   100.000
1 100.000   100.000   100.000
2 100.000   100.000   100.000
3 100.000   100.000   100.000
4 100.000   100.000   100.000
5 100.000   100.000   100.000
6 100.000   100.000   100.000
```

If you want specific columns to be converted to 3 digits, then you can use DataFrame.style in Jupyter Notebook.

```
df.style.format({'Rounded1': "{:.3f}", 'Rounded2': '{:.3f}'})
```

Output will be:

```
         Data   Rounded1    Rounded2
0   99.999824    100.000     100.000
1   99.999839    100.000     100.000
2   99.999982    100.000     100.000
3   99.999996    100.000     100.000
4   99.999997    100.000     100.000
5   99.999971    100.000     100.000
6   99.999942    100.000     100.000
```

Comment: Found that this is an excel feature where i need to convert the general string to text, and it starts working.